# Text Input element: How to select by ID and class?

Tags: jquery

I hope this refreshed question with more detail is now good.

I have a table with two columns. Child arrival time and child departure time.  I need to select a specific cell in a table either arrival or departure. The cell is identified by ID denoting the child, which is a variable, and by *class* called checkboxIn or checkboxOut. Here is the abbreviated HTML using class checkboxIn:

```
@foreach($children as $child)         //LARAVEL BLADE SYNTAX
    <tr class="child row">
                                
// Child's Name and ID Goes here - Abreviated

    {{Form::checkbox('timeIn',$child->child_id,false,['style'=>'margin-top:12px;'])}}</td>

    @if($child->timeIn && $child->timeIn !='absent')
        <td class="col-md-2 checkboxIn">  //CLASS "checkboxIn"
            <input readonly="readonly"
                   class="form-control" name="timeIn" type="text" id="{{$child->child_id}}"
                   value="{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($child->timeIn)->format('g:i A') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="timeinarray[]" id="timeinarray-{{$child->child_id}}">
    @else
        <td class="col-md-2 checkboxIn">  
            <input autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" type="text" id="{{$child->child_id}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="timeinarray[]" id="timeinarray-{{$child->child_id}}">
        </td> 
    @endif

// DOES A BUNCH OF OTHER STUFF

@endforeach
```

I need to be able to select the text input by ID (denoting the child), and by *class*: either checkboxIn or checkboxOut.

When I add  a class together with the ID, I get the error, *"Uncaught ReferenceError: checkboxIn is not defined"*.  Clearly, JS sees checkboxIn or Out as a variable, when it is indeed a class.  I have tried using the below syntax which does not work and gives the error:

```
$('td.timeInReset').click(function () {
    let id = $(this).closest("td").html("<button type='button' class='timeInReset btn btn-light'>Reset</button>").attr('id');

    $('input[type=text][id='+id+'][class='+checkboxIn+']').css({"color": "blue","text-align":"center",
        "border":"2px solid black"}).val('')
```

There is clearly something wrong with my syntax when adding the class, but I can not find it is the docs nor with Github CoPilot.

Comment: And is the `checkboxIn` variable actually defined?

Comment: Please show some HTML. For starters, IDs must be unique. If you have multiple elements with the same ID value you have invalid HTML. If your IDs _are_ unique, you probably want `hasClass()` to verify that the element has the class after you've selected it by ID. Also show your variables so we can see their values.

Comment: Please show us the code where are you defining the `checkboxIn` variable. Preferably provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue.

Comment: IDs are **unique**. Makes no sense to use any other selector besides `$("#"+ id)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, that's not quite true. It may be necessary to _also_ check for the presence of a class. In short, we need more information.

Comment: @isherwood true that, that class might signify a state. I rushed with my comment. Thanks

Comment: From your code, and provided HTML, `id` is `undefined` `let id = $(this).closest("td").attr("id")` as none of your `td`s have an `id`.   (as provided).   **Debug your variables** - ie `console.log(id)` just before the `$('input[type=text][id='+id+']` line.   If you do have an `id` then please update your question to include enough HTML/js for us to run that demonstrates the issue - do not include php code if your issue is with javascript, show us a rendered, complete snippet.  See [mcve].  [edit] and click `[<>]`

Comment: @freedomn-m May thanks for your feedback. I updated my question yesterday, over 24 hours ago with LOADS of details and HTML etc. The moderators have not released the updated version.

Comment: Yes - I see your question with your edit from yesterday; hence my comment "do not include php code" which was not in your original question.  I have voted to reopen given the edit is quite substantial - but, TBH, I thought it was closed needing more info *with the edit* (didn't realise it had been closed before that - can see in history).  So consider my comment above based on your edit.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I solved my own problem. Essentially my mistake was to put the child ID into every cell of the table thus creating the problem of identifying a cell by ID and class.  I have moved the ID now into the row and I now select a specific cell by the row ID and the class of the required cell. BTW my question is still closed. Cheers.

Comment: TBH it's unlikely your question will be reopened, I suggest asking a new question with all the details (included *rendered* HTML, no server-side HTML) then deleting this question.

Comment: For example, your code `$('td.timeInReset')` doesn't reference any HTML provided in the question, there's only `td.checkboxIn` - include enough HTML (not php/laravel/etc) and make a snippet.  Otherwise it'll just get closed again.